# Calculate age based on date and birth year

Tags: r, types, na

I am attempting to back fill NA with the average for foo$Birth.Year, then calculate an Age column:

```
foo$Birth.Year[is.na(foo$Birth.Year)]<-round(mean(foo$Birth.Year,na.rm=TRUE), digits = 0)
foo$Year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(foo$Start.Time), "%Y"))
which(is.na(foo)) # no values returned
foo$Age <- foo$Year - foo$Birth.Year
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Age, value = numeric(0)): replacement has 0 rows, data has 89051
Traceback:

1. `$<-`(`*tmp*`, Age, value = numeric(0))
2. `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Age, value = numeric(0))
3. stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
 .     "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)

table(foo$Age)
15  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35 
 1   2   3  12  32  43  58 155 217 324 357 384 388 362 360 350 280 304 249 241 

glimpse(foo)
Observations: 42
Variables: 4
$ Start.Time    <dttm> 2017-06-23 15:09:32, 2017-05-25 18:19:03…
$ Birth.Year    <dbl> 1992, 1992, 1981, 1986, 1975, 1990, 1983, 1981…
$ Year          <dbl> 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017…
$ Age           <dbl> 25, 25, 36, 31, 42, 27, 34, 36, 33, 38, 24, 53…
```

I'm getting age data, but I'm also getting that error.

The error stops the script and has to be stepped over. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the relevant parts of `foo` with the columns used?  Also, what is `which(is.na(ch))` doing?

Comment: Sorry, `ch` should be `foo` (not very descriptive variable names) but `which(is.na(foo)` is supposed to show the location of `NA` values in the dataframe. It returns nothing, so I assume I've provided values for all the `NA` found earlier.

Comment: It's more helpful if you can provide the dataframe in a format that can be easily copied and worked by others without having to recreate your data.  `glimpse()` isn't great for that.  Normally you would want to cut foo down to a minimum number of rows/columns that still demonstrate your issue, and then paste in the output of `dput(foo)`.  There's a lot of guidance on how to create a "reprex" or "reproducible example" you should look at on the Help page of SO.

Comment: @wackojacko1997 I created an input :-) see my answer

Comment: Sorry wackojacko1997, I haven't seen data attached to other posts I've read, so I didn't think it was wanted. I'm sure you don't want all 9k rows of data, but I guess it could be obvious that three rows of data might not be enough. I'll try to do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide an input (and I only get two complete rows from the `glimpse()` call, I created my own input. You can adapt the answer below to your own example:

```
# We set a seed, for the results to be reproducible
set.seed(0)

library(tidyverse)

today <- as_date("2023-08-06") # I have to set today's date this way, instead of using today(), otherwise it won't be reproducible any day other than today

df <- tibble(
    # get 100 random dates between today and 100 years ago
  dob = sample(seq.Date(today - years(100), today, by = "day"), 100, replace = TRUE))


# add in some NAs in random places to make it more similar to OP's data
df$dob[sample(1:100, 10)] <- NA

# get the average date, excluding NAs (unsure how much of a good idea this is statistically, but I digress)
average_date <- df |>
                  filter(!is.na(dob)) |>
                  pull(dob) |>
                  mean()

df |>
  mutate(dob = if_else(is.na(dob), average_date, dob),
         Age = interval(dob, today) %/% years(1)) # %/% is integer division
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 100 × 2
   dob          Age
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 1971-03-27    52
 2 1959-10-13    63
 3 1960-07-20    63
 4 1979-06-24    44
 5 1971-07-17    52
 6 1925-12-30    97
 7 2010-02-03    13
 8 2012-02-24    11
 9 2018-08-22     4
10 1927-10-13    95
# ℹ 90 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your comment about the wisdom of backfilling with average data is on point. That is a bad idea in this case. I would do better to exclude na values from my calculation.